# How make a dynamic or generated HTML page savable?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dynamic, dojo

I am still a bit new to dojo, javascript and HTML coding. I inherited ownership of an HTML page which is coded using dojo 1.4.2 (will be upgrading in the future) and javascript. Essentially the HTML page contains a form which is initially displayed to the user. After the user fills out the form and submits it, the form is replaced with generated content based on their answers.

This is done by using the answers in the form to reveal or hide various div elements that are already contained in the HTML file. So the form is hidden and some subset of other div elements are revealed.

We'd like this generated page to be savable by the user as a static HTML page. So essentially we want to save only the displayed divs to the file rather than the whole page. Currently, a save just saves a local copy which would require a user to re-submit the form on each view.

I was told this could be done by passing data to a service (possibly a JSP) which would handle this and pass back to the browser. However, I am not familiar with this and haven't been able to find any examples. Is there a way to do this and does anybody have any examples or documentation that I could be pointed to?

Ideally, I'd like to insert a save button which saves the generated content being viewed in the browser without actually creating a static HTML that will stay on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the content only in form elements (inputs), or are you updating DIVs/SPANs (other HTML elements) as well?

Comment: There are form elements initially in the top of the HTML but once you click the submit button. The "generated" content displayed is nothing but DIVs/SPANs, etc at the bottom of the HTML page which are revealed by updating the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a mechanism that makes changes to the page according to URL parameters (i.e. the contents of a parsed query string).

I.e. given a URL containing a query portion (e.g. *http://your.site.com/path/to/page?p1=true&p2=true*) the `Element`s mapped to *p1* or *p2* would show; others would not.

Comment: Given my experience and timeframe I am less likely to head down this path but thanks for the input.

Comment: We ended up going down this path due to restrictions in using additional tools. We also converted the HTML page to a JSP to make things easier. The combination allowed us to save a static copy.

Answer (score 5):

How about a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) like this?

```
javascript:document.location='data:text/html,'+document.all[0].innerHTML;
```

It works by accessing the HTML representation of the current DOM, and then redirects to a *new page* that's built from HTML markup using the [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

The new page can easily be saved using your browser's regular save menu-item.  Note that relative URLs won't survive this transformation, so the saved page may lose its stylesheet/script/image references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flash plugin to download dynamically created data. I wrote a small script [here](https://github.com/gitbuh/bhd) that does the trick.

Here is [an example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42482420/bhd/example/index.html) of the script.

Just drop the three things in [dist](https://github.com/gitbuh/bhd/tree/master/dist) wherever your other javascript files are. Include the `swfobject.js` and `bhd.js` scripts in the head. Include some html like this in the body: `<div id="dl_button"></div>`

On page load, run a script like this:

```
var dlBtn = new BHD.Button({
  // id of the element to replace with this button (required)
  id:'dl_button',
  // button image
  sprite:'buttons.png'
},function(){
  // set default filename
  dlBtn.setFile('untitled.html');
  // set file contents
  dlBtn.setData('<html>' + document.documentElement.innerHTML + '</html>');
});
```

Your "buttons.png" needs to look something like this (a sprite with 3 states layed out vertically):

[image: button sprite]

If everything was done right, clicking the button should prompt the user to download a copy of the current state of the page.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and try this this week before marking down a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using something like jQuery, it's simple to get all the rendered HTML content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   var rendered = $('html').html();   // store this in some variable   
});
```

The problem exists that you want to save the page, which cannot be done so easily in JavaScript, due to browser security restrictions, which prevent the browser from accessing the local file system.

Internet Explorer may be an exception, if using the ActiveX or execCommand (http://4umi.com/web/javascript/filewrite.php).  Otherwise, you'll have to use some third party tool/plugin (like Flash) as GGG has pointed out.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly, I can get the rendered content but the problem will still be allowing a user to save locally depending on the browser which can likely only be addressed by using some additional tool/plugin?

Comment: Exactly.  To be cross-browser, you have to use the additional plugin (like Flash), for security reasons.  Imagine if you browsed a site from a Google listing and it had the ability to write[/read] to[/from] your hard drive.  It could take your confidential information, or easily transmit viruses, without you doing anything other than viewing a web page.  That would be the most insecure thing ever.